# Lightbox with slider inside

Tags: javascript, html

I need to duplicate this Javascript function.
The idea is to pop-up three images;

1 img: Only one "Next" button - and close(x) button on the top right 
2 img: "Previous" and "Next" button - and close(x) button on the top right 
3 img: "Previous" and "Finish" button - and close(x) button on the top right 

I'm thankful for any help or tips!

**Here is the code:** http://justpaste.it/3l6j

The images needs to slide, not fade. If i go with another code. Like this: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: Maybe i can use this one instead? Then i need help positioning the buttons accordingly to the images in the slider http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide/

Comment: Missing semicolon in  `$.facebox({ div: '#friendsDlg' })
`

Comment: Hm okay. Yeah maybe. The code still works.. I need help reproducing this code.